# Modify order field

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id |order  | name    |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | 2     | John    |
| 2  | 1     | William |
| 3  | 4     | Karl    |
| 4  | 3     | Michael |
+----+-------+---------+
```

I want to Move Karl from the fourth place to the second so the order field of Karl will be set to 2, John 3 and Michael 4.

Is there a way to update the table with only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that Karl is already in fourth, and you know that he's moving *up*, then this should do it:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET order = (order - 1) % 3 + 2
WHERE ORDER BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

For a more reusable query, if someone is moving from position B to position A in the list (A < B), you would do this (substitute real numbers for A and B):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET order = (order - A + 1) % (B - A + 1) + A
WHERE ORDER BETWEEN A AND B
```

If you want to move someone down the list, from position A to B, instead, do this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET order = (order - A - 1) % (B - A + 1) + A
WHERE ORDER BETWEEN A AND B
```

and everyone in between will be updated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a conditional update:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = CASE other_field
    WHEN 1 THEN 'value1'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'value2'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'value3'
END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

They help me come up with a single query that updates the order field from any position A to any position B:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET order=MOD(order-LEAST(A,B)+SIGN(A-B),GREATEST(A,B)-LEAST(A,B)+1)+LEAST(A,B)
WHERE order BETWEEN LEAST(A,B) AND GREATEST(A,B)
```

Comment: I did some tests and it worked, but not working all the time. I changed to three queries to do the job.